# issue when running the sample SpeechToText_WPF_sample

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, bing, azure-api-apps

When we try running the sample SpeechToText_WPF_sample (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows) with a free subscription key, somtimes it works but frequently we are blocked with :

--- Start speech recognition using microphone with ShortPhrase mode in en-US language ----
--- Microphone status change received by OnMicrophoneStatus() ---
********* Microphone status: True *********
Please start speaking.

and after a few minutes (maybe 1 or 2 minutes) we get this message (and all radiobutton are disabled) :

--- Microphone status change received by OnMicrophoneStatus() ---
********* Microphone status: False *********

i don't think its a network problem because when i test with a bad SubscriptionKey i get instantely this error message :

--- Error received by OnConversationErrorHandler() ---
Error code: LoginFailed
Error text: Transport error

could you help us please ?

Regards,